# Is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty {n\sin({1\over n})}$ divergent or convergent? Justify the answer.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Using this fancy list:

[image]

I think I can rule out the options 1 through 5, but I'm not sure. The book I have gotten this problem from does not have any examples that use a trig function. I think I'll need to use option 6, what do you guys think? Or should I use a comparison test?

Thank you for any help, I'm really bad at recognizing these series and what I should use to solve them.

Comment: Did you try checking the limit of the terms as $n \to \infty$?

Comment: Why do **I** have to justify the answer?

Comment: @KennyLau Sorry if it seems subjective, I did not mean to word it that way. It is just how it is worded in the book. I think it means just to show how to figure out if it is convergent or divergent.

Comment: @DevHeavy Then this is why it's important to ask the question that *you* have, not copy-paste the book's problem statement....

Comment: @user296602 I understand that. I like to show my whole process of trying to solve the problem, but with this one, I don't even know where to start. Should I use an integral test? Is it an alternating series? Geometric? etc? It almost seems impossible to figure this out in a reasonable time frame, and I can't get any other help.

Comment: @DevHeavy two people already gave you the same hint.

Comment: @DevHeavy Did you read my comment, or Mark's comment?

Comment: @MarkViola I assume that n is not going to be important here, so as n gets bigger in $1\over n$ that means it is going to 0, and $sin(0) = 0$. Does that mean it is convergent to zero?

Comment: @DevHeavy no, because $n$ is going to infinity, and you cannot disregard it as it contributes to the product

Comment: @DevHeavy $\lim_{n\to \infty} n\sin(1/n)=1$.  Does that suffice now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}x\sin(1/x)=
\lim_{u\to 0^+}\frac{\sin u}{u}
$$

Comment: Going off of that, since the denominator will be zero, that means the limit DNE and the divergence test says that is divergent, correct? Thank you.

Comment: @DevHeavy No, not at all. You should recognize the limit as involving the derivative of $\sin$ at zero.

Comment: @user296602 That limit precedes knowledge of that derivative. It is a fundamental result of elementary calculus.

Comment: @zhw. The asker's comment implies that they have the belief that $\lim_{u \to 0} \frac{\sin u}{u}$ does not exist because of the denominator. I was trying to point out that this is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider the limit $$ \lim_{x\to\infty} xsin(\frac{1}{x}) $$
It is equivalent to another you limit you may have seen before. $$ \lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{sin(x)}{x} $$
It should be obvious at this point that you can use the divergence test to show that the sum diverges.

Comment: Ehm. Isn't this a normal "sinc" function?;)